# setContentView doesn't attach click event for a button

Tags: java, android

**Requirement**

Application requirement is when the user installs and opens for the first time, he will be shown `LoginActivity` and once he logs in successfully, he will be asked to enter 4 digit `passcode`, to use in future, if application remains idle and phone gets locked.

**Design**

I've decided it to design both as in `One Activity` i.e. `MainActivity` and load `contentView` of `LoginActivity` on certain condition.

**Code Part**

*MainActivity.java*

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    isUserValid=false; //just for testing on initial screen i.e. Login
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(isUserValid) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    else{
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(isUserValid) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    else{
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    if(isUserValid) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    else{
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }
}
```

*LoginActivity.java*

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    //Attaching click event to button
    Button btnValidate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.validate_code);
    btnValidate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Functionality
        }
    });
}
```

I am aware that I could have attached click event directly to button in `activity_login.xml` but then it works only when we use `setActivity()` instead of `setContentView` and am supposed to use `setContentView` here as I do not want user to navigate between these 2 views on click of back button. I've also tried to attach click event for button in `onCreate` on `MainActivity.java` under else condition as below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    isUserValid=false; //just for testing on initial screen i.e. Login
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(isUserValid) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    else{
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        //Attaching click event to button
        Button btnValidate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.validate_code);
        btnValidate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                  //Functionality
             }
        });
    }
}
```

But that did not help. further, I went forward and tried to attach the event in both `onStart` and `onResume` states of both the activity, nevertheless, did not work. The click event is not at all triggered. I assure that button with that `id` is present in `activity_login.xml`. What is that am committing mistake here. I am not getting the functionality and am in just starting stage of learning Android. Hope to find some solution for this behavior.

Comment: alternatively you can state onClick funtion in XML only by using

android:onClick="btnValidate"

and define a funtion in MainActivity like

`public void btnValidate(View view){
  Your Functionality goes here
}`

Comment: @NishantPardamwar tried that.. Still no luck.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Fragments instead of different content views.

activity xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    if (isUserValid) {
        ft.replace(R.id.content, new LoggingFragment(), "loggingFragment");
    } else {
        ft.replace(R.id.content, new MainFragment(), "mainFragment");
    }
    ft.commit();
}
```

fragment xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
       android:id="@+id/button"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment

```
@Override
protected View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null);

    Button btnValidate=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.validate_code);
    btnValidate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Functionality
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

Comment: It's bad practice but if u really want u can try this one, make your activity implements View.OnClickListener and use
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
           if (v.getId() == your id) { //do smth}

    }

Comment: It would be helpful if you give more details on implementing with fragments, so that I can try it..

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
check this tutorial

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend using multiple fragments however you can still add a content view programmatically as below :

```
View login = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_login);
addContentView(login, new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

you can use the inflated login to find views and attach listeners.

To remove the login you can use the

```
((ViewGroup)getWindow().getDecorView()).removeView(login);
```

Again I don't recommend this approach. Using fragments or custom dialogs will be better.

Hope this will help.